# System not loading after installing proprietary AMD drivers

Tags: drivers, 15.04, radeon, fglrx

Ubuntu 15.04. Radeon HD 6620G + 7670M dual graphics.

With Ubuntu's default open driver everything works well, but I experience low fps in games and short battery life. When installing proprietary drivers (from `SoftwareSources->AdditionalDrivers`, not from AMD's website), I get the error message:

```
fglrx-updates-core 2:15.200-0ubuntu4:fglrx-updates-core 
kernel module failed to build
```

After rebooting the system starts in low-graphics mode, but loading freezes (user login screen does not appear). After [removing the proprietary driver](https://mwop.net/blog/2014-11-03-utopic-and-amd.html), my system works again.

How do I get to a working system with AMD's drivers?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` your install, [a fix of fglrx that fails to compile](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fglrx-installer/+bug/1479913) has been released a few days ago.

Maybe, you also suffer from this bug.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this problem will be solved by running

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic
```

rebooting and running

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall fglrx-updates
```

In some cases linux-headers are not installed when the system is upgraded to 15.04.